# Not able to make oauth 1.0a request from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, oauth

I am trying to make signed oauth 1.0a request using "GCO Auth". I am able to get data successfully using GET but when i am trying to login api (which takes POST param) i am getting NULL response.
Here is my code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [GCOAuth URLRequestForPath:@"/api/v2/secured/user/login"
                                    POSTParameters:nil
                                    host:BASE_URL

                                    consumerKey:CONSUMER_KEY
                                    consumerSecret:CONSUMER_KEY
                                    accessToken:nil
                                    tokenSecret:nil];
NSMutableURLRequest *requestOne = [request mutableCopy];

NSData* result = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:requestOne  returningResponse:nil error:nil];
if(result == nil)
    return nil;
NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:result
                                                     options:0
                                                       error:nil];

NSLog(@"%@",json);
```

All i am getting in response is NULL, however, on the sample API page (provided by API provider) i am getting correct data using same consumer key and consumer secret. 
I think i am missing the oauth signature part while making the request but i don't know how to do it.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.